# Multiple classes map with Jquery and load the content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I have a Div of Class

```
<div class='navigation five-icons'></div>
```

and i want to load a URL which returns html inside it, how can i select that div with jquery, 
what i have tried is

```
 $('.navigation .five-icons').load('URL');
 $('.navigation.five-icons').load('http://www.astuffaday.com/shot/menu.php');
```

but no use.

Comment: `same-origin-policy` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Comment: Anyway, the correct selector is the second one you tried (the one without the space).

Comment: @Aioros XMLHttp Request is Not allowed, showing in console is there anyway to allow cross domain ?

Comment: I'm not an expert in that area, but I don't think it's going to be easy. The previous link from pXL is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about loading but you can use below code to select more than one class

```
$('.navigation, .five-icons')
```

Comment: Sure, you can, but that does an OR, not the AND that they need.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the data asynchronously?
Use `$.post()` or `$.get()`

```
$.post('filename.php', {'name1':'value1', 'name2':'value2'}, function(result) {
   alert(result);  // result has the HTML content returned by filename.php
   $('#resultDiv').html(result);  // resultDiv will have its contents

   // Now you need to get only particular div
   // You can use 'find()'

   // Something like this may help  [Have not been tested]
   var data = $('result').find('.navigation .five-icons');
   alert(data);
})
```

**References**
[$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
[$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)
[$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)
[$.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)
[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: The `.load()` function is a shorthand for a `$.ajax()` call, as are `$.post()` and `$.get()`; this won't change a thing.